# Access vectors in a list with an array of indices in R

Tags: r, arrays, list, vector, indexing

I have a list containing 3 vectors, e.g.:

```
> test_list
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "d" "e"

[[3]]
[1] "f" "g"
```

I want to access elements of those vectors using an array containing the vector indices, e.g.:

```
> indices
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    2
[2,]    2    2    2
```

This is the desired output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "e"  "g"
[2,] "b"  "d"  "g"
```

I found the following way to do it:

```
test_list <- list(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d", "e"), c("f", "g"))
indices <- matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
t(apply(indices, 1, function(row){mapply(`[[`, test_list, row)}))
```

Is there a cleaner, more idiomatic way?

Comment: Maybe `mapply("[",test_list,as.data.frame(indices))`.

Comment: I’d probably write it as `sapply(seq_along(test_list), function (i) test_list[[i]][indices[, i]])` but that’s actually even longer. But it (a) only uses a single higher-order function, i.e. it doesn’t nest loops, and it (b) does not double-transpose the implicit matrix, so it’s conceptually simpler. (Actually I’d use `lapply` instead of the error-prone `sapply`, and then explicitly transform the result into a matrix, but that’s *even longer*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option involving `purrr` could be:

```
map2(.x = test_list, 
     .y = asplit(indices, 2),
     ~ .x[.y]) %>%
 transpose()

[[1]]
[1] "a" "e" "g"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "d" "g"
```

Or a `base R` solution using the idea from the comment provided by @nicola:

```
mapply(`[`, test_list, asplit(indices, 2))
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using backticks instead of string quotes for R object names — the fact that R allows otherwise is sheer idiocy that we should do our best to pretend doesn’t exist. that said, very nice answer.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph it is always a pleasure to have a comment from you, I have learned a lot from your feedback since I'm on this site :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option in `base R`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(test_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(test_list))))   
`dim<-`(out[cbind(c(col(indices)), c(indices))], c(2,  3))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "e"  "g" 
#[2,] "b"  "d"  "g"
```